# How to run a task for the first time instantly using ScheduledExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading, background-thread, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a task which I need to run every 6 AM in the morning. I have my below code which does the job and it is using `ScheduledExecutorService`.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int delayInHour = hour < 6 ? 6 - hour : 6 - hour + 24;

System.out.println("Current Hour: "+hour);
System.out.println("Commuted Delay for next 6 AM: "+delayInHour);

scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTask(), delayInHour, 24, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

**Problem Statement:-**

With the above code, suppose if I run it now, then it will execute `MyTask()` in the 6 AM in the morning. But what I need to do is, whenever I am running my program for the first time, then it should execute MyTask() instantly and next run should happen at 6 AM in the morning.

Is it possible to achieve with the above code?

Comment: Why not just immediately run the task yourself?

Comment: I need to send out an email around 6 AM in the morning so that's why I am doing it like this but I was thinking if I am running it for the first time, then it should get executed instantly and then next run should get executed around 6 AM in the morning.

Comment: @user2809564 I think @chrylis means why not `new MyTask().run()` it yourself?